# Git: forcing tests before pushing to local or remote master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, testing, rspec

Is there a way so that git refuses to commit to local or push to remote master if tests (rspec) are failing ? Thank you.

Comment: Don't know about restricting commit to local but yes push to remote can be restricted easily by using pluggins like `Jenkins`, `Hudson`, `Travis`

Comment: You will need pre commit git hooks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a git pre commit hook which executes `rake spec` (taken from [Tips for using a git pre-commit hook](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/)).

```
git stash -q --keep-index
`rake rspec`
RESULT=$?
git stash pop -q
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```