# Git reject local commit based on some conditions

Tags: git

Is it possible to reject a local commit based on certain conditions. For ex: don't accept any commit if lock.txt exists in local repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: forcing tests before pushing to local or remote master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999568/git-forcing-tests-before-pushing-to-local-or-remote-master)

Comment: yes, use a hook! Something like: `ls | if [[ $(grep lock) ]]; then exit 1; fi`